# Strange floating point numbers behavior in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, numbers

What's wrong with the following code?

```
$(function() {
    var ok = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var x = 100; // if we use new Number(100) here, the test will pass
        $.each([1,2], function(k) {
            x -= 5.5; // if we use integer (or declare a variable with value 5.5 outside this scope), the test will pass
            return false;
        });
        if (x + 5.5 != 100) {
            fail();
        }
    }
});
```

This test passes successfully in all browsers but fails in Safari 6 (6.0.2 (8536.26.17)).
Is there any error with the code? Or it's a browser bug? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Antelle/2zMA6/) is the example on jsFiddle. It outputs:

```
OK: 94.5 + 5.5 = 100
FAIL: 95 + 5.5 = 100
```

Comment: What happens when you try to parseInt(x) === 100?

Comment: It outputs false after the loop and true before the loop. But this is expected because it's a floating point number, not integer, so it could have a small fraction. But why we get 95 instead of 94.5? This is not a small fraction.

Comment: In Safari, it runs ok whenever I bring up the console, but it says fail when I run again with the console closed.

Comment: Antony, exactly. I've noticed this strange bug in a quite large javascript project: sometimes unit tests failed. But each time when the console was open they were passed. It was very hard to localize the problem but I've found it.